# Auto add query string for admin URL Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want auto add query string "_adminToken" for admin URL, example:

```
http://mydomain.site/wp-admin/plugins.php => http://mydomain.site/wp-admin/plugins.php?_adminToken=123
http://mydomain.site/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page => http://mydomain.site/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&_adminToken=123
```

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup', 999 );
function my_theme_setup() {
     add_filter( 'admin_url', 'filter_admin_url' );
}
function filter_admin_url( $url ) {
     $query_string = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY );
     return !$query_string ? $url . '?_adminToken=123' : $url . '&_adminToken=123';
}
```

But it not working, somebody can help me?